# Trouble getting simple cakephp search form to work

Tags: mysql, forms, cakephp-2.0

I keep getting the error that my variable is not defined in my view.  This is actually my first ever search form (not just for cake) and I'm sure I must be doing it wrong.  here is my controller code:
**UPDATE**  Here is the new code, both for the controller action and the html form.

```
<?php
$options = array('house' => 'House', 'condo' => 'Condo', 'hotel'=>'Hotel');
$attributes = array('legend' => 'Property:<span style="font-style:italic">(Please select one)</span>');
echo $this->Form->radio('Unit.type', $options, $attributes);
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Search'); ?>
```

which gives me this output:

```
<form action="/lodgings/search" id="UnitIndexForm" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
<fieldset><legend>Property:<span style="font-style:italic">(Please select one)</span></legend>
<input type="hidden" name="type" id="UnitType_" value=""/><input type="radio" name="type" id="UnitTypeHouse"  value="house" />
<label for="UnitTypeHouse">House</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="UnitTypeCondo"  value="condo" />
<label for="UnitTypeCondo">Condo</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="UnitTypeHotel"  value="hotel" />
<label for="UnitTypeHotel">Hotel</label>
</fieldset>
<div class="submit">
<input  type="submit" value="Search"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Now my controller logic:

```
function search() {

$result = array();
if (isset($this->params['url'] ))
{
$type = $this->params['url'];
$conditions = array("Unit.type = " => $type, 'Unit.active'=>1);
$result = $this->Unit->find('all', array('conditions'=> $conditions));
$this->log(print_r($result, true));
$this->set('type', $result);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Lodgings Controller and want to use the Unit model, did you mention the unit model to use ?

```
public $uses = array('Unit','Lodging');
```

EDIT:

view

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(false, array('id'=>'search', 'url'=>array('controller' => 'lodgings', 'action'=>'search')));             
$options = array('house' => 'House', 'condo' => 'Condo', 'hotel'=>'Hotel');
$attributes = array('legend' => 'Property:<span style="font-style:italic">(Please select one)</span>');
echo $this->Form->radio('type', $options, $attributes);
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Search'); ?>
```

Controller:

```
function searchr(){
      $result = array();

      if (isset($this->data['type']))
      {
          $type = $this->data['type'];
          $conditions = array("Unit.type = " => $type, 'Unit.active'=>1);
          $result = $this->student_info->find('all', array('conditions'=> $conditions));
          $this->log(print_r($result, true));
          $this->set('type', $result);

      }
   }
```

Comment: Yes it has been loaded under the $uses variable.

Comment: Cake directs to my search page, and my page has <?php debug($type); ?>.  Cake tells me ...."Undefined variable: type [APP/View/Lodgings/search.ctp, line 1]"

Comment: the problem is that if (isset($this->params['url'] )) returns false and as such your variable $type is not assigned/set and hence you search.ctp does not find the variable

Comment: I think that may be because the url being shown when it goes to the search page is this:  /lodgings/search?type=&type=house.  Editing the OP to show how I reworked the code.

Comment: @HeatherWalters Kindly check the updated answer. In case you get any error, try to use `print_r($this->data)` to analyze the data return from the view

Comment: Ok, this is now giving me a "The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows".

Comment: @HeatherWalters kindly check your query condition. The error is coming from mysql select statement

Comment: The solution was that I had to paginate this query and also contain it, as Units hasMany other things like Complex, Image, Location, etc.  Cake just wanted to join too much all at once.  Thank you for your help, i am marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" value="house" name="data[Lodgings][type]">House
```

Where the model is Unit, shouldn't it be

```
<input type="radio" value="house" name="data[Unit][type]">House
```

Comment: See, that's what I thought too, and that is what I had originally but I get the same error that 'type' is undefined.

Comment: After `$result = $this->Unit->find('all', array('conditions'=> $conditions));` try logging the returned data to the debug log with `$this->log(print_r($result, true), LOG_DEBUG);`

Comment: Ok, I did that.  Now where do I find the output for that?

Comment: Heh.  that file doesn't exist on my server.  The only log I show is the error log.

Comment: OK, so instead try removing the `LOG_DEBUG` from the logging statement above so it goes to the error log instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7633/discussion-between-heather-walters-and-jackofalltrades)